# Is there a way to use .selectedSegmentIndex instead of .buttons["name"] in UITest?

Tags: swift, localization, screenshot, ui-testing, nssegmentedcontrol

When doing my element query in my UITests, to take screenshots of the different segmented control value, an error is thrown when translation comes into play because I use `.buttons["name"]`, and the name is in English and is not being translated as expected.
It has been translated from the storyboard. So I would like to find a simpler solution.

Can I have the .selectedSegmentIndex instead of the button name that has translation error in UITest, or is there another way to fix this issue?

```
XCUIApplication().scrollViews
  .children(matching: .other)
  .element
  .children(matching: .other)
  .element(boundBy: 0)
  .children(matching: .other)
  .otherElements
  .segmentedControls["MySegmentedControl"]
  .buttons["name"] // How to add this value to be .selectedSegmentIndex = 1?
  .tap()
```

Comment: Did you try `app.segmentedControls.buttons.element(boundBy: 1)` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error:
Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Descendants matching type SegmentedControl from input

Comment: I mean `.segmentedControls["MySegmentedControl"].buttons.element(boundBy: 1)`, instead of `segmentedControls["MySegmentedControl"].buttons["name"]`. you tried so, right?

Comment: I tried this solution but triggers the same error.

Comment: btw, did you access to segment control before with the code you share? You need to launch first, then access through the `app`. not like `XCUIApplication().segmentedControls `

Comment: All of this is done in the setup(), I just shorten the code to make it readable on StackOverflow. The flow is correct until I hit the code I shared in another language than English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218277/discussion-between-omerfarukozturk-and-roland-lariotte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an element at specified index using `element(boundBy:)`

For your case;

```
app.scrollViews
.segmentedControls
.buttons
.element(boundBy: 1)
.tap()
```